# I don't have "Dynamic Web Project" option in Eclipse new Project wizard

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

I have download the Eclipse IDE for Java developer, HELIOS. I click 'File -> New -> Project...', but I only have "General, CVS, Java project, Examples". I would like to be able to create "dynamic web project", why do I not have this option?

I searched from internet, and the reason is probably I don't have Eclipse Web Development Tools, but how can I get it?

-----------EDIT-----------

I know by install Eclipse IDE for Java EE developer can solve the problem. **But**, I am working under **Linux Ubuntu**, how to get Eclipse Java EE version for **Ubuntu Linux** machine?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think you need the Web Tools Platform package for this. Not very sure though. You can add it to your current eclipse through Help > install new software.

Then add the software repository site location for WTP for your version of eclipse. This is how you can install plugins in eclipse.

Answer (score 97):

Not all of them are required (I think), but after installing the components listed below I got the "Dynamic Web Project" template added to my Eclipse (Indigo). The list is:

- Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools
- Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools
- Eclipse Web Developer Tools
- Eclipse XML Editors and Tools

You can install those packages by clicking on "Help" > "Install New Software", selecting the repository that corresponds to your Eclipse build (i.e http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo for Indigo). The packages are grouped under "Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development".

Comment: Thankyouthankyouthankyouthankyou!!! Never would have come up with that one myself. Here's a happy programmer's smile :)

Comment: I only needed "Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools" and none of the others.

Comment: I just tested this, "Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools" is the correct answer as per @nostromo

Answer (score 30):

"http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler"(If you have Eclipse Kepler)

Based on your eclipse choose above link and copy in

1. help>Install new software
2. paste in "work with" click add
3. give any name you want - plugin
4. In the list select>"Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development">Eclipse Java EE

   Developer Tools. select and install it.
5. After restart you will have your Dyanmic web project option.

Thank You.

Like me if it worked please

Comment: For me, clicking on "add" just messed everything up. Simply pasting the relevant link in "work with" did the job.
The necessary plugins were exactly where you said they would be. Thank you :)

Answer (score 22):

You only need to install

> Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools

and you will be able to see "Dynamic web project" wizard.

Answer (score 9):

Download [Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/heliossr2), everything you need should be included inside. This is the most painless way of obtaining Web Development Tools.

If you want to leave your existing Eclipse IDE, you can go to 'Help -> Install New Software' and find WDT to install them, although I haven't personally tried to go this route, so I can't guarantee everything will work out of the box.

**Edit**: not sure if it's included in Ubuntu's repository. One other way to do it is to download Linux 32-bit (or 64-bit, depending on your machine) version of Eclipse EE, but you'll have to check if it's the source you have to compile yourself, or an already compiled binary.

Comment: I am working under ubuntu linux, how to get that under ubuntu?

Comment: What has this to do with ubuntu? - Use the link darioo provided, download Eclipse JEE for linux, unpack the archive and start Eclipse.

Comment: I did not notice that there are linux downloads of elipse, that's why I ask with ubuntu.

Comment: @Mellon The download links (including Linux versions) are available on the right hand side panel in the provided link.

Answer (score 6):

Fwiw, I downloaded the standard Java EE version of the Mars version of Eclipse, and ran into the same deal -- didn't see a Web option if I tried File >>> New >>> Project wizard.

The good news: Probably no extra installation needed.

It looks like what I wanted was to select the `Other` option rather than the `Project` item (strangely this is what comes up when you hit Ctrl-N, but that also lets us know we're probably on the right track):

[image: Screenshot of the new project menu hierarchy with "Other" highlighted.]

After you select "Other", you'll see the "Select a wizard" screen, where you can select "Dynamic Web Project" and profit.

[image: Dynamic Web Project highlighted in Select a wizard screen.]

Comment: Downvotes without explanation make it difficult to improve the quality of answers on the site. **Leave me a note.** If this answer stinks, tell me why, and I can improve -- or delete -- it!

Comment: Although I did not downvote, but believe it was done because your answer was not in line with OP's question. His issue is that he is missing the entire Web folder in which the Dynamic Web Project option appears. And maybe you thought of it that he is not able to locate that option. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

1. HELP
2. Install New Software
3. In Work With input box paste this url:     http://download.eclipse.org/releases/{version}/
   Replace version with your eclipse's version (eg: LUNA)
4. Hit enter
5. Underneath box will have different options, select package of your need.

Comment: You can use "latest" instead of "version"

Answer (score 2):

Maybe Eclipse WTP plugin has been accidently removed. Have you tried re-installing WTP using [this location](http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates/) ? If I were you I would have reinstall Eclipse from strach or even better try [Spring ToolSuite](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts) which integrates with Google Plugin for Eclipse seamlessly (usign Extenstions tab on STS Dashboard)

Answer (score 2):

Just download any eclipse with "EE" letters

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, you may find that going to the top right corner of your page in Eclipse and click "Java EE" instead of "Java" will solve your problem. I had EE installed correctly like you, and this solved the issue for me. Hope I helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Go to Eclipse --> Help

and click--->Install new software

then you can see a window ...There a click add

Then put below url in url box: http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/juno/

i am having juno

if u have any other means put that name .
then click ok.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to check dynamic web app in "other section" i.e File>New>Other>Web or type in "dynamic web app" in your wizard filter. If dynamic web app is not there then follow following steps:

1. On Eclipse Menu Select HELP > INSTALL NEW SOFTWARE
2. In work with test box simply type in your eclipse version, which is oxygen in my case
3. Once you type in yur version something like this "Oxygen - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen"will be recommended  to you in drop down
4. If you do not get any recommendation then simply copy " http://download.eclipse.org/releases/your-version" and paste it. Make sure to edit your-version.
5. After you Enter the address and press enter bunch of new softwares will be listed just ubderneath work with text box.
6. Scroll, find and Expand WEB, XML, Java EE .... tab
7. Select only these three options: Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools, Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools,Eclipse Web Developer Tools
8. Next, next and finish!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to handle this is to install the full package installer with all weblogic add ons from the oracle site.  This will install eclipse with all the features/plug ins you need.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/oepe-network-installer-2371168.html

Answer (score 0):

This helped me find the "Dynamic web project" in Eclipse 2020-12 version. Restart the eclipse and go to file->new->other->web and you will see
project will be available.

Answer (score 0):

This option might be missing because more than one and other than `Tomcat runtime` is selected. At the marked spot I was shown that I have selected `Java JDK runtime`. After unselecting it `Dynamic Web Module` reappeared.

[image]