# Could not start a A web project for Eclipse Kepler - For MAC OS

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I have recently installed Eclipse Kepler for MAC and couldn't start a new web project (static or dynamic, the whole 'web project' option does not exist) and had a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531402/newbie-in-eclipse-i-dont-have-dynamic-web-project-i-am-under-linux-ubuntu) hoping that will help me and it didn't.

I have also installed:
Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools
Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools
Eclipse Web Developer Tools
Eclipse XML Editors and Tools

As was suggested, didn't help either.
Help/suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your tooling is not working. Make sure your Eclipse kepler is supporing the EE development. 
You can download it from here. This is working for me.
[Click Here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/kepler/SR1/eclipse-jee-kepler-SR1-macosx-cocoa.tar.gz)